# The order of uplink and unhandled downlinks on Live Objects

Tags: lora, orange-api

I have questions about sending uplink and downlink

1. I'm receiving uplink from FIFO queue. I discovered that uplink sent later arrived first to my server despite uplink's order seems guaranteed on LiveObjects console. Do the queue ensure uplink's order?
2. How do long unhandled downlink remain? I seen that downlink sent 12 hours ago was arrived to my device.
3. Are unhandled downlinks stacked? If the previous downlink was not sent to the device and a new downlink arrives, how is the previous downlink handled? (remove or stay etc..)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Live Objects guarantees the delivery of the messages in the order as they arrive in the platform from the network. Look into your data message you have two informations: "timestamp" which is the time of the LoRa gateway who transmit the message to the core network, and "created" which is the time of the message that arrive in the Live Objects platform. You may have slight differences
2. DL Messages sent from LO are kept in the Core network until the target device wakes up and open its RX frame
3. I've no detail about that. Contact your Live Objects support to have more informations

regards